# Storyboard warnings while using nested stackviews

Tags: storyboard, xcode7, uistackview

I have a vertical stackview in my storyboard with four nested horizontal stackviews contained within it.  The vertical stackview is pinned to a UIView (light blue) which in turn is pinned inside the main storyboard view.

Inside each horizontal stackview I have inserted three UIButtons.

The alignment for all of the stackviews is set to fill, and the distribution is set to fill equally.

The issue I am having is that I receive 16 warnings when I build the app.  Each nested horizontal stackview, and all of the buttons warn that their frame will be different at run time.  But when I run the app all appears to be fine.

The screenshots show my preview screen behaving as I would expect it to, along with a shot of the app running on an iPhone 6+.  Not sure what I am doing to cause these warnings.

[image: Storyboard view]

[image: Preview screen]

[image: Warnings]

[image: iPhone 6+ shot]

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the warnings. It seems that Interface Builder can't handler StackView correctly yet. The layout should still work as expected. At least it did for all my projects.